# What's the safest/easiest thing I can add to my credit report

Tags: credit-score, australia

I'm in the excellent range on the credit score, but recently it started falling due to lack of (recent) credit report entries. Since it's only 1pt / month, over last half a year, I don't care that much but I was wondering if there's anything simple I can do to stop the fall.

I don't really need to get anything expensive at the moment, and I'm happy with the one credit card I have. What's the simplest thing I can do that will get reported. Preferably I don't want it to involve an initial (reportable) credit check either.

Location: Australia

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic transaction on credit card to stay active](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/66497/automatic-transaction-on-credit-card-to-stay-active)